# How can I search and replace using wildcards in values where I need to change row numbers recurringly?

Tags: excel, vba, search, replace, wildcard

I am importing values from a CSV file into a workbook of an Excel file. Then I filter and sort these values using VBA. Let's call this sheet "raw_values". These values are then read out and processed in another sheet ("processed_values").

Next, I would like to clear all cells on "processed_values" and copy a row of formulas from sheet "Settings" to all rows in the table on "processed_values". However, since the references in the formulas on this sheet refer to the "raw_values"-sheet, these references change due to earlier sorting and filtering. For example, in "raw_values" the first 10 lines are removed due to filtering and lines 11 through 20 are placed at the bottom due to sorting. The references in "processed_values" become corrupted or point to the wrong rows.

How can I correct the wrong references to the correct row? I came up with this, but using wildcards doesn't work:

```
    Selection.Replace What:="raw_values!" & "(*)??", Replacement:="raw_values!" & "(*)36", LookAt:= _
         xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
         ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

With this I want the following:

```
raw_values!*?? -> raw_values!*36
Where * = the column and ? = the row
```

result:

```
Import!D21 -> Import!D36
Import!G22 -> Import!G36
Import!H21 -> Import!H36
Import!J19 -> Import!J36
```

I hope it is somewhat clear what I want to achieve and that you can help me with this. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand what you are asking, but if you want to have

cell A1 in sheet "**processed_values**" to refer to cell A1 in "**Import**",

you can use the indirect and address formulas, e.g.:

```
=INDIRECT("Import!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))
```

which removes the need to search and replace specific references.

You can offset that if needed by adding or subtracting, for example:

```
=INDIRECT("Import!"&ADDRESS(ROW()+2,COLUMN()-1))
```

in cell B1 will reference cell A3 of "**Import**".

So for the range A1:Z100 the VBA code would be:

```
Range("A1:Z100").Formula2R1C1 = "=INDIRECT("Import!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))
```

Comment: Please improve the readibility of this comment, everythong is stucked together.
Make spaces and improve the formatting.

Comment: @RobyB I gather you must be referring to my code, but I have no idea what traditions there are around adding spaces. Where would I find out about that?

Comment: I improved the readibility, and used the button {} to format the code. 
And added spaces and new Line, just to divide sentences and concepts.
And gave a +1.

Comment: @RobyB Thanks! I see how the line breaks help the visual readability, and I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to get that code format.

The only things I didn't understand were why you would bold the word "offset" and italicize the second line.

Comment: When you write, you have a bar, at the top, above the area you are writing.
Select the word you want to emphatize, and then click on the 'B' for example for the bold, click on the {} to format as a code, or the "I" to format cursive. It is just the top bar with the different options you have to format when you write.